# How can i secure the particular rest api using SSL client authentication in spring boot reactive application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, ssl-certificate

[1] that the "/v2/getData2" particular API need to be secure by SSL client certificate authentication in my service and I currently have a CA certificate.pem, CrtCertificate.pem and privateKey.pem file based on the .pem file I need to authenticate the "/v2/getData2" API only.

while I call the "/v2/getData2" API it requires client certificate file authentication.

here is my code,

```
 @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       return http
               .csrf().disable()
               .authorizeExchange()
               .pathMatchers("/v2/getData2").authenticated()// authentication require
               .anyExchange().permitAll().and()
               .x509().and()
               .httpBasic().and().formLogin().disable().build();
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)